# Dataweave MuleSoft 4 - Dynamic Output Header in CSV Files (True or False)

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Scenario:

Today, i have a flow to create a simple CSV with dataweave and ftp component, i receive the data by text/plain file, the process in fact is when the record its 1 , i'll put the header = true, the next records will be false, just need the firts recor put the header to add the column names. To solve this validation today i have a choise component to generate with 2 similar dataweave the only change that has the first record its with the next code "output application/csv separator=",",header=true" and the secod dataweave "output application/csv separator=",",header=false", this post i generated beacause i need your help if exist different way to solve this design, or just with a one dataweave inside this detect that the variable record change the header = true or false depends by the variable record

Actual Code:

if the variable record = 1

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator=",",header=true
---
payload.rows map {
  "number" : $.number default '',
  "total" : $.total default 0,
}
```

else

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator=",",header=false
---
payload.rows map {
  "number" : $.number default '',
  "total" : $.total default 0,
}
```

I would wait if there is a possibility (join both dataweave because the difference is the header):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator=",", header=(if(vars.record == 1) true else false)
---
payload.rows map {
  "number" : $.number default '',
  "total" : $.total default 0,
}
```

NOTE: this is just doubt i don't know if exist any way to do.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It should be automatic if the records are processed together by DataWeave. For example if all the records are in the payload as a stream, or a list. Are the records processed separately?

Comment: yes, all the records are taken by the input file ( text plain ) and iteration in "for component" one by one and its a list

Comment: Please add how the input file is parsed and used in the foreach to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define [dynamic properties](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-writer-prop-mule) using the `write` function. Note that it requires actually setting the output writer to **binary** and declaring the mime type as CSV so Mule propagates it as such. This is because CSV writing happens at the function level:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv with binary
var data = payload.rows map {
  "number" : $.number default '',
  "total" : $.total default 0,
}
---
write(data, "csv", {"header": (vars.record == 1), "separator": ","})
```